# GreenDao deleting a row in a junction table

Tags: sql, sqlite, greendao

I have a junction table | USER_ID | ORDER_ID |
now, when I'm trying to delete a row in the table I'm getting 
`does not have a single-column primary key` error.

Now of course both of the table's columns are FK, and I can't add a PK column in it because it's a junction table.

I'm using :

```
userJoinOrdersDao.delete(userOrderObj);
```

Does anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The junction table's primary key consists of both columns. This is not supported by greenDAO.

http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/ says:

> While greenDAO does not support n:m relations directly as of now, you can model the join table as a separate entity.

... which would require a separate PK column.

---

Does an order really need to have multiple users?

Comment: It's not really an Order - User relation. I used them just for the example. Im guessing that I need to build a PK from both FKs columns and then trying to delete it